# Managed Metadata import/export in subsites

Tags: 2010, managed-metadata, powershell

I am attempting to export/import the managed data in a library of a subsite on my intranet.  When I attempt to use the taxonomy tools that are up on Codeplex, or when I use code such as [this](https://jyothiregode.wordpress.com/2011/02/19/create-termset-programmatically-using-powershell-in-sharepoint-2010/), I am only able to see the metadata at the top-level site.

For example, the site on which I'm trying to pull data is http://mysp.domain.com:51475/ia.  The code samples, et. al. only pull from http://mysp.domain.com:51475.

Thanks in advance,
Larry